# Find a toolbox to display data in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

now i design a form with C#, and want display my data like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfIAL.png).

I try to find a toolbox item in C# can help me create it, but i don't see.
I hope you can tell for me know if you know about this item or different method to create like this.
Thanks so much.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [TreeView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/treeview-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Add treeview control via tool box
go to form load function
put treeview control name "treeView1"
add following code i add node dynamically

```
        TreeNode Main1 = new TreeNode("Main1");
        TreeNode Main2 = new TreeNode("Main2");
        TreeNode Main3 = new TreeNode("Main3");
        TreeNode Sub1 = new TreeNode("Sub1");
        TreeNode Sub2 = new TreeNode("Sub2");
        TreeNode Sub3 = new TreeNode("Sub3");
        TreeNode Sub4 = new TreeNode("Sub4");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(Main1);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(Main2);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(Main3);
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(Sub1);
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(Sub2);
        treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(Sub3);
        treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add(Sub4);
```